# Can I invoke different TestNG tests by changing test data?

Tags: testng, rest-assured

BACKGROUND:
I have REST APIs that I am testing using Rest Assured. I use TestNG for test execution. However, the API responses are different for different values of the Accept request header (application/xml OR application/json). For e.g. - tags present in the xml response appear with different keys like  appears "employeeNo".

Therefore, I have to write a 2 different tests (assertions and parsing) - one for the xml response and other for json response, everything else remains the same. For e.g. - updateEmployeeNameJsonTestSuite and updateEmployeeNameXmlTestSuite.

CURRENT APPROACH: 
I have two different test data files and two different test suites - one for json responses and one for xml responses, each is invoked using -suiteName option provided by TestNG.

PROBLEM:
I want to parameterize the value of Accept Request Header in a test data file and then have TestNG programmatically decide which test to invoke. I have not been able to find a good approach to achieve this programmatically. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't u parameterize your test and pass the response type as a parameter in the testng xml. And then depending on that parameter you can make the request header. We do the same for our webservice testing. And write a generic method for validation again which will determine what type of response is going to come depending on the value of the parameter.

```
<suite name="My suite">
  <parameter name="ResponseType"  value="Json"/>
  <test name="Simple example">
  <-- ... -->




 @Parameters("ResponseType")
    @Test
    public void testNonExistentParameter(@Optional("xml") String ResponseType) { 
// Use Response type
}
```

Same can be done for @before methods

This way you will have only one test suite which can be run for both response types

Comment: While I ended up using @DataProviders, this was definitely useful in leading me in the right direction.